# Airflow plugin Changes cached, updates to hooks/operators not reflecting

Tags: python, airflow

Airflow is caching my plugins (`plugin/myplugin/hooks/etc.py`) file, i have tried everything, restarting my computer renaming `myplugin` folder to `myplugin2`  but it still goes to look inside `plugin/myplugin/hooks/etc.py`

How can i remove cache from this and reflect my changes in my plugin's hook